# Point-to-point building of medium- frequency circuits, ground plane implementation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pcb-assembly, ground-plane

I build audio projects and small logic control circuits using point-to-point on perfboard (see pic of a recent build).

[image: point-to-point on perfboard]

As you can see this allows me to select wire gauge in accordance to the currents at various parts. When the board is finished, tested and washed I spray paint a clear enamel on the underside. I have built circuits running up to 450V like this without problems, but these are all low frequency projects.

Now I want to build a switcher-style power supply running at 50kHz. For the moment I am only in the exploratory stages as this is terra incognita for me. Is this building method any good for medium frequency work? I seem to recall having seen HF projects built in dead-bug fashion without issues, that can't be any worse no?

The only potential issue I see could be parasitic capacitance between the copper pads. If it is a problem, I could dissolve the unneeded pads using etchant - I have done this for boards that are connected to mains in order to reduce the potential for arcing. This is done before soldering parts - I design my boards with autoCAD so I know in advance which pads need to be kept.

The second point is about the use of a ground plane; this seems mandatory for switching circuits. I can implement it with a piece of plain PCB stock under the perfboard with drilled pass-through holes for the few pins that need to connect to it but there would be a space of almost 1/8" between the two boards, can this be a problem? If so I can place the plain PCB stock on a spot that isn't under parts so it is in direct contact but it will be of smaller area of course.

Alternatively, could a large-gauge piece of wire be used instead of a ground plane? If a low-impedance path is all that is needed that could fit the bill. A 18AWG wire has as much copper as a sizeable PCB plane no? There might be problems due to skin effect in the wire though...

I *could* etch a bona fide PCB but I'd rather not - I hate drilling dozens of holes using those crazy-thin drill bits, and I'm not convinced at all about consistancy of home-etched PCBs tracks physical/electrical properties. This is the reason I build point-to-point on perfboard.

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance for any help!
-Joe

Comment: Check out a technique called "Manhattan" building.  This uses a combination of dead-bug as well as top-mounting components on tiny pads cut from a sheet of copper-clad circuit-board material.  It is (relatively) easy to do and is probably faster than the perf-board that you showed.  The substrate is a sheet of copper-clad circuit board which gives a great ground-plane with which to work.

Comment: Radio Amateurs (HAMs) use this technique to build RF circuits into HF & VHF frequency ranges.  For the tiny pads: I use a small Roper Whitney Jr hand punch to make pads 1/8" & 3/16" diameter from a sheet of 1/16" thick blank PCB material.  A tiny dot of CA glue holds them in place.

Comment: One of so very many examples <http://www.sdmakersguild.org/the-art-of-manhattan-style-circuit-construction/>

Comment: For protoboards with ground planes, Busboard has ones for surface mount in their SPx series and Twin Industries has them for through-hole in their 8100 and 8200 series. 8200 actually provides two planes. Vector has them too but they are overprices by about 300%. Allows for things to be a bit neater than dead bugging on a plain copper board.

Comment: @Dwayne Reid Yes you remind me, I have seen projects built like that many years ago and they were pretty cool too! Thanks for your comments I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: I know you're probably not looking for that kind of advice (and I think Neil's answer is pretty fantastic!), but: you getting a custom PCB for your purpose usually does *not* imply etching and drilling yourself; I couldn't do that for the e.g. 5€ a 10-stack of boards from JLCPCB costs me, and I definitely couldn't do it at the precision, for no money in the world, lest I use the money to buy a PCB factory :)

Comment: (this goes far enough that it's even economically feasible to design custom protoboard like the one you show in your photo, with a few predefined connector and power distribution pads and traces, and a lacquered-over ground grid on the opposite site, that you can scratch free to get a good ground at every point on the board; plus, while your protoboard does look pretty good, still, it's still of the annoying brown material and the holes are unaesthetically off-center in the pads. Again, even just ordering 10 custom boards just to get 10 higher-precision breadboards is 0,5€ a board.)

Comment: @DKNguyen Thanks for the suggestions, these boards do look nice, I think I'll use some for the final builds

Comment: @Marcus, thanks for your comments, I welcome all input. I do have nicer FR4 perfboards for build of my more "upscale" designs ;-) I'm checking the PCB fab you mention, but a prototype would still be needed, and I'm not sure I could test a switcher on proto-board.

Comment: @Joe that's understandable (though, if you feel like testing it, hm design a board? Throwing down devices that are already in e.g. KiCAD's parts libraries is not much of an effort, and so is laying out a board from that :) The tricky thing is probably figuring out what the right amount of test points is to poke around your board easily without being confusing)

Comment: @Marcus I've got to say, 2$ for 5 professionnal PCBs is damn tempting. A project like in the photo takes me an afternoon to build... Apart from the very simple things I simulate all my designs in LTspice and most of the time they work right the first time. I design the boards in CAD anyways as it is simpler IMO to produce an efficient layout, I guess I could take that first step into custom PCBs. Thanks again for your insights.

Comment: @Joe glad it's inspiring you to "take that risk". The annoying thing is waiting for boards to arrive :) I do use KiCAD these days, but earlier works were mostly Eagle. It really all works quite smoothly these days, though I'm surprised none of the contract PCB manufacturers aggressively pushes a "order from us!" plugin for KiCAD etc., which would be rather easy to write... BTW, if you're in the US: Oshpark makes very good boards, pretty quickly, if you're in Europe, Aisler is closest to the local equivalent of that.

Comment: @Marcus I'm in Canada, I welcome any shop you could recommend here. Otherwise no problem I'll go with JLCPCB or this other shop nextPCB who offers 0$ on first order to attract newcomers. KiCAD is being installed as I write this, I like the fact it's open source and they have a Linux version, I have flushed Windows away more than a decade ago :-)

Comment: I ordered from oshpark myself, to Germany. It's nice folks, and the quality is really quite good, and I remember them being in Portland, Oregon, so postal-wise not a bad spot for shipping into a lot of Canada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For switcher frequencies, you can forget about problems caused by excess pad capacitance, it's just not the right order of magnitude to cause trouble.

However, grounding is a more serious issue. It's not actually necessary to use a ground plane. It is necessary to have a ground return running close to all signal traces, to minimise the area of the current-switched loops that you will be creating in a switcher design, and to ensure that ground currents in one part of the design don't create stray voltages in other parts.

A gridded ground can work quite well. Something like a 10mm or 1/2" spaced grid of wires on both x and y axes, soldered together at every intersection, would be more than enough like a ground plane for switcher frequencies.

If you do use an additional board for a plane, the 1/8" gap should be fairly negligible.

What most RF engineers would do is start from a ground plane, and then mount components above it. You can get sets of pads, IC footprints, and transmission lines, on adhesive-backed copper clad. Another way to do this for cheap is to cut up some copper clad into tiny squares and strips, and epoxy or super-glue these down to the ground plane. Hint, 15 minute epoxy goes off in a few seconds if you hold a soldering iron to the pad.

Comment: Many thanks! I think I'll experiment will all the techniques you mentionned along with my original two-board sandwich idea, checking for transients in each.